# Sharepoint Audit Logs

Tags: sharepoint

Good evening everybody,

In my company we working with a SharePoint Server OFFLINE, and we are trying to audit logs from share files, delete files, etc.

In the Site we setting like we read in Microsoft Community but the Logs dont give us much info we need, just some info but it's not clear

[Site collection audit setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCdWk.png)

And we know the Logs are left in the URL: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS

My question if you know more ways to check all info with logs from Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, audit logs are the only option to konw information about share files nad delete files.

Logs in the Program Files are about behind scenes of services in the SharePoint.